# is it possible to customize bugzilla fields ( text fields, text area etc)?

Tags: perl, bug-tracking, bugzilla

I have one product and several components of this product. Each component have several reported bugs.

Every bug has been assigned to a specific user.

I want to customize some text fields/areas for that user, so that he/she can not edit that specific field.

I also want to customize some text fields/areas for for Bug Creator (who files the new bug) so that he/she can not edit his/her posted bug.

Is it possible ?

Can we customize these fields via making changes in code ? or by installing some plugins ? or any other way ?

Permission/restrictions on groups are also not working. For example I created 2 groups A and B. Group A have full permissions (Create and Edit bug) but group B don't have any permission but only READONLY. But there is no difference between the user's rights those either belongs to group A or B (both can create and edit bugs). How i can limits the users belongs to group B ?

Only Developer should able the create/edit the fields but Client should not able to edit the bug.

---

The following discussion was very helpful for me. As i have ProductA, ProductB and groups Client, Developer.

http://groups.google.com/group/netscape.public.mozilla.webtools/browse_thread/thread/98efcae88fe84d6d/51c8deb672402e09?lnk=gst&q=permissions+for+all+users#51c8deb672402e09

**Answer:**

Product A:

ReadCreateA: Entry/Mandatory/Mandatory/-- EditA: --/NA/NA/Canedit Similar for Product B.

### For this, you need to give editbugs privileges to developers. If you want to restrict editbugs privileges in other products, you need to set up a group they are not a member of as xx/xx/xx/Canedit for the other products. In your particular setup, this is already covered by the EditA and EditB groups.

(Works fine ) When I use the above guide , it works perfectly except posting comments. I am getting following error while posting comment --> "You are not permitted to edit bugs in product Product A"

but I want users of "Group UsersA" should not edit the bug (that is fine) but must be able to post the comment.

How can I manage this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to modify code to accomplish this. See http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/cust-change-permissions.html for details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

I had a look at this document and make the changing 
(comments the code) in Bug.pl file but nothing happens. 
Permission/restrictions are also not working. For example if we create 2 groups A and B. Group A have full permissions (Create, Edit bug) but group B don't have any permission but only readonly. But there is no difference between the user's rights those either belongs to group A or B. How i can limits the users belongs to group B ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is very nice discussion and I think my 75% problem has been solved.

[Link](http://groups.google.com/group/netscape.public.mozilla.webtools/browse_thread/thread/98efcae88fe84d6d/51c8deb672402e09?lnk=gst&q=permissions%20for%20all%20users#51c8deb672402e09)

but in this case user are not able to post the comments, now I need to find the ways that user should not able to edit the bug fields but user could post comments anyway.